# Regex to match slash does not work

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex to match these:

```
/web/search/abc
/web/search/employee/999999999
/web/search/employee/78524152
```

But not this:

```
/web/search/employee/123456789
```

I wrote the following regex for Java, but it does not seem to be working.

```
/web/search/(?!/(employee/123456789)).*
```

Can someone tell me the correct regex to do this?

Comment: Your `/` is doubled in the negative lookahead

Comment: @anttix It is used as a negative lookahead here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you double the `/` in the lookahead. Try with:

```
/web/search/(?!employee/123456789$).*
```

Comment: Thank you. The pattern /web/search/employee/1234567891111 shall return false.

Answer (score 3):

What you tried is : `/web/search/(?!/(employee/123456789))` can be represented as

[image]

You need to change it as `/web/search/(?!employee/123456789)` can be represented as

[image]

Comment: what is the website where you get these kind of images?

Comment: @AmitJoki -- From debuggex

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
/web/search/(?!(employee/123456789$)).*
```

The slash was doubled in the negating look-ahead group.

Comment: "the direct slash is a special symbol in Regular Expressions" <-- no it isn't, except when you use a language which can accept regexes with in slashes

Comment: @fge is right, the `/` is not a special character in java regexs.

Comment: Well, Java Regexes and Classical Regexes are slightly different. Slash IS a special symbol in Regexes (check the link I provided), but not in Java Regexes

Comment: @Danek And the asker's regex should be for java.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, sure, but it was not stated in the question body at the beginning. I've edited it though :)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Tags are not a part of a question and used for search and grouping purposes. 
Then please consider checking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask under "Be Specific".

Comment: Sorry but no, the `/` has never been a special character in _any_ regex dialect. Nowhere is it mentioned in the link you provided.

Comment: @fge, wow, you've got me here! It is a special character in Ruby though. But it is my bad, sorry everyone for misinforming.

Comment: @Danek Nowhere in that "how to ask" page does it say that everything has to be in the body of the post.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat it states that the question should be specific/clear, but tag is not equal to question!

Comment: @fge `/` is a special character for regexes in _some_ languages, but not all.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, anyway, the answer was found, so let's not put too much pressure on that brilliant place :)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat "languages", not "regexes" ;) Even in JavaScript you can use `new Regexp()` and the first argument is a regex as a string; in such a case no need to escape the `/`.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, I would kindly ask you then to provide me with a link for that direction. I've edited about 92 posts, and 80 of the edits were successfully approved. Each of them had a keyword in the header.

Comment: Dear @TheGuywithTheHat, for your further reference I am posting here this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title
The first point of the chosen answer states that the header should include enough information to understand the question without reading tags.
Feel free to ask me if you have got any other doubts regarding proper questions asking on SO.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, sure, but in our case by adding "in Java" we are just adding more information about the particular environment in which we are facing some problems explained in the body of the question. The conversational tone is not being broken in that case.
The only thing I require from headers is that they make sense, and, in my opinion, "Regex to match slash does not work in Java" makes more sense than "Regex to match slash not working".
Also, thanks for that link, it looks very useful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49694/discussion-between-danek-and-the-guy-with-the-hat)

Answer (score 2):

I would say

```
str.contains("^/web/search/(?!employee/123456789)")
```

satisfies your requirements.

Online demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/dF1eU9